# ImportXML scraping with different date

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import an exchange rate from [this website](https://eximbank.com.vn/WebsiteExrate/ExchangeRate_vn_2012.aspx)

I'm using the `importXML` function and have the following syntax

```
=IMPORTXML("https://eximbank.com.vn/WebsiteExrate/ExchangeRate_vn_2012.aspx","//span[@id='ExchangeRateRepeater_lblTTBUYRT_0']")
```

but I don't know how to import information based on other date, I only know how to import information in one specific date.

This is the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5bnqWnTXNrmMcrolXXLsjw26pAow5WUtBw0ReNBObU/edit#gid=0&range=B2) I'm working on it.

Any help!

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Sry, I've edited

Answer (score 0):

scraping with the changed date is not possible in this case because picking the different date won't change the URL, therefore, there is no way how to tell Google Sheets to look up stuff for a different date. the best course of action would be to find another website that hosts the same data.